# How to add loading in this template in Django?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form in template that submit POST request to test_connection view. The test_connection view takes at least 1 minute to process so on that time I want to add `Testing connection...` message to the user. When the user presses submit button I want to show loading button. I have tried this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="loading">
  <img id="loading-image" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
 $(window).ready(function() {
    $('#loading').hide();
  });
```

**CSS:**

```
#loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
}

#loading-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 240px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

It's not working though. What's wrong?

Comment: any error in console?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#loading').hide();
});
```

**OR**

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#loading').hide();
});
```